# Find a divergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_1+...+s_n}{n}$ exists.

Tags: divergent-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent series, and let $S = \lim s_n$, where $s_n$ is the nth partial sum.

I need to find the following:

Find a divergent series $\sum a_n$ such that 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_1+...+s_n}{n}$ exists.

My series that I chose was: $\sum_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$ Was looking to see if this series was a correct choice for this solution

Comment: alternate $a_n$ between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: so $(-1)^n$????

Answer (score 2):

Your choice will not work. The partial sums of $1/k$ go like $$ s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} \sim \log(n)$$ so $$\sum_{k=1}^n s_k \sim \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k) \sim n\log(n)$$ and $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n s_k \sim \log(n) \rightarrow \infty.$$

**HINT**
You want the partial sums to "average out" to something even if the sequence does not converge. For instance, if your partial sums were $1,0,1,0\ldots,$ that doesn't converge but it does average to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: would $(-1)^n$ work then?

Comment: @jeb650 You mean $a_n = (-1)^n$ so that $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$? What are the partial sums $s_n$?

Comment: $-1+1-1+1+...+ 1^ n$ and so on

Comment: @jeb650 That's what the series looks like. What does the sequence of partial sums $s_n$ look like?

Comment: isn't that the sequence of partial sums $s_n$?

Comment: @jeb650 $-1+1-1+1\ldots$ is a sum, not a sequence. Write it like $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\ldots$

Comment: @jeb650 Hint, if $n$ is even, we get$$(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots+(1-1)$$If $n$ is odd...

Comment: @jeb650 $s_1 = a_1 = -1,$ $s_2 = a_1+a_2 = -1 + 1 = 0,$ $s_3 = -1 + 1+ -1 = -1,$ etc... So the sequence $s_n$ is $-1,0,-1,0,-1\ldots$ and $\lim s_n/n = -1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not correct (although it is a bit peculiar to say "Let $a_n$ be a convergent series..." and then ask to find a divergent series $a_n$).

At any rate, with your series $a_n = \frac1n$,
$$
s_n = H_n
$$ 
the $n$-th harmonic number.  It is well known that 
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n H_k = (n+1)H_n - (n+1)
$$
So you would have to have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)H_n - (n+1)}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[H_n + \frac{H_n}{n}-1-\frac1n\right]
$$
which diverges because of the first term $H_n$.

The problem is easy if you allow $a_n$ to have alternating signs (for example, 
$a_n = (-1)^n(1+1/n^2)$. That does ot converge (although it also does not diverge to infinity).

If you demand that $a_n$ be strictly positive, then you have more of a challenge.

Comment: Hm, strictly positive... It hardly looks possible.

Comment: No wait, not strictly positive, for if we include $0$, this is trivial.

Comment: @SimpleArt: In fact, I think it's not possible with $a_n$ nonnegative: in general, if $s_n$ is a nondecreasing nonnegative sequence and $s_n \to \infty$ then $\frac{s_1 + \cdots + s_n}{n} \to \infty$ as well.  This is because if $s_n \ge L$ then $\frac{s_1 + \cdots + s_{2n}}{2n} \ge \frac{L}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah, obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

The classic example is Grandi's series:

$$1-1+1-1+\dots=DNE$$

But

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}n=\frac12$$

Where

$$s_n=\overbrace{1-1+1-1+\dots}^n$$

Comment: so would that series just be $(-1)^n$

Comment: @jeb650 Yes, it would be.

Comment: so then $\sum (-1)^n$ would be the answer?

Comment: @jeb650 Yes, it would be an appropriate answer.  Indeed, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_of_Grandi%27s_series#Ces.C3.A0ro_sum) will probably help you even more.

Comment: okay thank you I will go with $\sum (-1)^n$

Comment: @jeb650 Ok then.  You may also wish to see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: The limit after "But," as written, is obviously not correct.  Rather, we have $s_1=1$, $s_2=0$, $s_3=1$, etc. so that $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} s_k =n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}s_k=n$.  Hence, $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n s_k=\frac12$.

Comment: @Dr.MV look better now?

Comment: @simpleart Unfortunately, no.  How is the numerator approaching $n/2$?  As written, it alternates as $\pm1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV ... I am a goof